# How to search something without touching the search history in vim?

Tags: vim

I sometimes use searching to navigate in a document. But I don't want the search pattern to be recorded. Is using a function like `search()` is one way to go?

*Appendix: I just want to search for a particular pattern so I can make a map for that. The only concern is how to avoid messing up the search history?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use search() and it does not add to the search history.  Just so something like `:call search('pattern')`.